# Change maximum size of picture-in-picture window in Sierra

Tags: macos

Does anyone know how the maximum size of the picture-in-picture window in macOS Sierra can be changed? I would really like to be able to enlarge it.

Comment: Are you not able to grab a corner of the video and drag to resize it, just like with any other video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file with settings is located at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.pipagent.plist

You can use http://www.nightproductions.net/prefsetter.html to edit this file and set the new dimensions.

[image: Here is how it looks like]
I tried changing the values, however those got reset to 0.25 / 0.225 once I restart picture in picture.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be the last state, so the system can use it the next time you open pip